# Run a loop that ajax loads more elements until an element is found

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function which loads the next page or results in without refreshing. This works fine, but what I'm aiming to do is run this in a loop until a certain element is loaded in through the ajax call.

**jQuery**

```
var ajaxPageNumber = 2;
function infiniteResults() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/?page=' + ajaxPageNumber,
        success: function(data) {
            ajaxPageNumber +=1;
            if (data.length) {
                $('.table tbody').append(data);
            } else {
                $('<div class="text-center"><strong>No more results remaining.</strong></div>').insertAfter('.table');
            }
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
        var i = 0;
        while (($('.desired-element').length < 1) && (i < 50)) {
            infiniteResults();
            i++
            console.log("More results loaded");
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Max tries reached, fail);
    }
});
```

The problem I'm running into is that it fires all 50 of my loops ajax calls at once, so it appends page 2 of the data 50 times. This happens even though in my test, the desired element is on page 4.

Is something like this feasibly possible in jQuery/javascript?

Comment: The Ajax calls are asynchronous witch means you don't get a result immediately when you call your infiniteResults(), but once the HTTP request get the answer, so the loop will continue while the ajax request is not loaded yet. @donohoe gave you the right answer, and this is only an explanation ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return the promise that `$.ajax` returns, and use that in a kind of loop, by calling a function recursively (although the stack will not grow, due to the asynchronous nature):

```js
var ajaxPageNumber = 2;
function infiniteResults() {
    // return the jQuery promise
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/?page=' + ajaxPageNumber,
        success: function(data) {
            ajaxPageNumber +=1;
            if (data.length) {
                $('.table tbody').append(data);
            } else {
                $('<div class="text-center"><strong>No more results remaining.</strong></div>').insertAfter('.table');
            }
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    (function repeat(i) {
        infiniteResults().done(function () {
            if ($('.desired-element').length == 0 && i < 50) {
                console.log("More results loaded");
                repeat(i+1);
            } else {
                console.log("Max tries reached, fail");
            }
        });
    })(0);
});
```

Comment: Hm for some reason I'm getting "Cannot read property 'done' of undefined" when trying this method.

Comment: Did you include the `return` statement before `$.ajax`?

Comment: D'oh! Didn't notice that, sorry. Trying it now

Comment: That did it! Got it all figured out and squared away now. Appreciate the pointers!

Answer (score 3):

All the calls happen in sequence very rapidly. Without knowing your full intent I would have it so the infiniteResults is only called again after it has completed, so these happen sequentially and not together.

**I haven't tested this** but this is what I am thinking...

```
var ajaxPageNumber = 2;

function infiniteResults() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/?page=' + ajaxPageNumber,
        success: function(data) {
            ajaxPageNumber += 1;

            if (data.length) {
                $('.table tbody').append(data);

                if (ajaxPageNumber < 50) {
                    infiniteResults(); // NEW
                }

            } else {
                $('<div class="text-center"><strong>No more results remaining.</strong></div>').insertAfter('.table');
            }
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    infiniteResults();
});
```

Comment: Ah, I actually managed to accomplish most of what I was hoping for just by setting async to false on the ajax call. =]

Comment: @Octoxan, Setting `async` to `false` is *not* recommended practice: you block the browser this way, which degrades the user experience.